# R Keras flatten layer - got an array of shape 1

Tags: r, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am trying to build a model in R Keras with TensorFlow that just has a flatten layer. Here is a snippet of the code:

```
model <- keras_model_sequential() %>%
  layer_flatten(input_shape = c(lookback, dim(train.data)[-1]))

model %>% compile(
  optimizer = optimizer_rmsprop(),
  loss = "mae"
)

history <- model %>% fit_generator(
  train_gen,
  steps_per_epoch = 500,
  epochs = 20
)
```

`lookback` is 1200 and `dim(train.data)` is `(13155, 3)`. The input to the flatten layer is `(1200, 3)` and I expect it should output a 1D vector of 3600.

`train_gen` returns a list of 2. The first is a 3D matrix with dimensions `(129, 1200, 3)` and the second one is a 1D vector with dimension `(129,)`.

However, I get the error:

```
Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : 
  ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_15 to have shape (3600,) but got array with shape (1,)
```

I don't know why this is happening. If I add a `layer_dense(units = 1)` it works but I don't understand why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The target shapes are incompatible: you provide as target a vector of size of 1 (i.e. `(129,)` means 129 sample labels with size one), however the model's output shape is `(None, 3600)` so it expects vectors of size 3600. And that's why when you add a Dense layer with one unit the problem is resolved: the Dense layer's output shape is `(None, 1)` and you provide `(129,)` and they match with each other, hence no issue to complain about.

Comment: how can I fix this problem? I want to have just a single flatten layer and to get the output from it. Basically, I am trying to learn how the flatten layer works.

Comment: @user2840286 Then you need to modify the `train_gen` to return as labels an array of shape `(129, 3600)` i.e. basically the flattened version of inputs.